# getStaticProps return object which will be created from multiple fetched urls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In `next js` in the `getStaticProps` function I am fetching multiple `URLs` which results shall be exported as props to the component. I am using a `map function` and I don't know how many URLs I will fetch ( they have been generated automatically). that's the problem: I am fetching the data dynamically. In the end, I would like to have a `JSON` or an array that contains all the fetched data.

My idea was that I am creating an empty `JSON` object at first and then push the `fetched` data into it. But as the `JSON` object already exists (it is just empty) it will be returned by the `getStaticProps` function. So I always get an empty `array` in the following components.

So my question is: How can I save the promise from every fetch into one object and return the object only at the time that it is filled with data?

EDIT

The object `result` is coming from a fetch too. Plus: At First, I wanted to make it easier to read for you but now I am thinking that this plays also an important role (so I will not hide it from you): I am mapping through the result-object twice. I go through it the first time, to find the proper Json Object. Then I am mapping through this proper object. Additionally, I added the Promise.all() method in the following:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
const result = await getUrl(someId);

  const temp = await Promise.all(
    result.modules.map((module) => {
      if (module.name == "proper") {
        module.selection.map(async (object) => {
          const id = object.ID;
          const response = await getNewUrl(id);
          return {
            title: response.acf.title,
            subtitle: response.acf.subtitle,
          };
        });
      }
    })
  );


      
  return {
    props: {
      temp,
    },
    revalidate 120, 
  };
}
```

Current error: `` Error serializing `.temp[0]` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value. ``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
    const result = await getUrl(someId);

    const temp = await Promise.all(
        result.modules.flatMap((module) => {
            if (module.name == "proper") {
                return module.selection.map(async (object) => {
                    const id = object.ID;
                    const response = await getNewUrl(id);
                    return {
                        title: response.acf.title,
                        subtitle: response.acf.subtitle,
                    };
                });
            }

            return [];
        })
    );

    return {
        props: {
            temp,
        },
        revalidate: 120,
    };
}
```

Comment: I think this should be the right approach but it is not working. Maybe it is not working because the object `result` is also a fetch which I am doing right before? How should I handle this?

Comment: @KerryKilian Edit the question to include more details about the problem (errors, most likely?).

Comment: @KerryKilian I have updated the answer now - seems like you needed to use `flatMap`. I return an empty array since that will be flattened into "nothing".

Comment: Thank you so much!! But I found another solution which is probably correlating with your's: I am saving the first map as own variable and then doing the ```Promise.all()``` on this variable. I will explain it tomorrow in another answer as it might help others. But thank you very much also for your new answer. I will check it in the next days :)